# Can't find files after unsuccessfully extracting rar to mounted webdav on Debian Linux

Tags: debian, filesystems

I unrared the big parted archive in my Debian Linux to a mounted WebDAV folder:

```shell
unrar e file1.rar /mnt/dav
```

When the process was complete, I went to the folder `/mnt/dav`, but apparently something went wrong and the file manager froze. I rebooted OS - but there were no files in WebDAV.

However, I ran out of disk space. This means that the files are saved somewhere on the hard drive.

I can't figure out where these files are. Maybe there is some kind of cache folder?

Comment: Did `unrar` output any messages? Mounting a file system masks the mount directory: you might find the files in the /mnt directory itself, not where you thought the target was mounted.

Comment: unrar completed successfully. in my opinion there was a problem connecting to webdav and thus these files were stored somewhere in the local system. thanks, I'll look in the /mnt folder

Comment: The /mnt folder - there is nothing there. the mount point was disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Using the du utility, I found where these files were saved in
`/var/cache/davfs2`. And in the `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` you can configure WebDAV caching.